# Setting window settings based on html file (through icon properties)

Tags: html, properties, window

I have coded a date calculator for my co-workers to use which is a very simple, single page html file.

A couple of years ago I saw a friend play with the settings of a html file so that it would open in its own browser window (not a new tab) with no toolbars etc. It basically functioned as a freestanding app.

How can I achieve the same outcome? (said friend no longer works here, so I can't ask him...)

I feel like it had something to do with dragging the URL to the desktop, then changing something in the "Web Document" tab... Does anyone know?

Comment: here's what I have so far: 1) open the file in chrome. 2) Click tools (three dots at top right) 3) More tools. 4) Tick "Open as window". 5) Click Create. 6) go to the properties of the app you just created (on your desktop). 7) Do something there..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open any website in chrome (not the file you are converting to an "app" - just a normal website)

2) Click tools

3) More tools

4) Create shortcut

5) Name the app and save it

6) Close the browser

7) Right click the app (probably on your desktop)

8) Go to Properties > Shortcut

9) Change the part of "Target:" that says "--app-id=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefg" to "--app="file:///C:/file_path_goes_here/filename.html"

10) Apply